# Excel Unable to remove Em dash and replace with En dash

Tags: vba, excel

Anyone know an excel formula or a VBA code for excel to replace Em dash with En dash. I just cant figure it out. My `VLookup` formula is not working for cell A1 which contains value 'WARSAW - ICSD RED – EB' as there is a long dash in text.

I've already tried excel formula `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"—","–")`

Also below VBA code:

`Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Replace What:="—", Replacement:="–", lookat:=xlPart`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the string: "WARSAW - ICSD RED – EB"
by me this code works:

```
Sub changer()
    Dim str As String
    str = Cells(1, 1).Value
    str = Replace(str, "–", "-")
    Cells(2, 1) = str
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1;CHAR(151);CHAR(150))
```

Comment: Nah that doesn't work unfortunately. Im getting an error. I Also changed the formula to =SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(151),CHAR(150)) but it just returns same vakue thats in cell A1